# Will three generations of particles exist if massless?

Tags: mass, symmetry, quarks, leptons

It seems there would be nothing to tell them apart if they were all massless. But can a symmetry breaking mechanism (if that were the generations' origin) make three where there was only one?

If the generations are present also without mass, must there then be something else to differentiate them?

Comment: Is that the right link? I cannot see anything about Higgs

Comment: I am so sorry i posted the wrong link. [This](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-known-apparently-elementary-particles/the-known-particles-if-the-higgs-field-were-zero/) is what you are looking for hopefully